# Node http 404 response always pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm writing a small server in node to run a templating script whenever a html file is requested.

My problem is pretty basic. Whenever a file is requested that doesn't exist I want to send a 404 response. When I request a single file that doesn't exist everything is fine. But when a `html` file links to `css` or `js` files that doesn't exist the request to those files will be pending until it times out.

[404 response http://ux.gl/image/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-01%20at%2018.00.57.png](http://ux.gl/image/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-01%20at%2018.00.57.png)

I'm using the node [`http`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module.

This is how I set the 404 response:

```
fs.exists(process.cwd() + req.url, function(exists){
    if(!exists) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write("Not Found");
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    // File exists
}
```

What am I missing? I have no issues with existing files.

#### Edit

I checked how it looks for a file under apache, and it's pending there too. I've never noticed this behaviour before.

I guess Chrome, and maybe other browsers, just stops downloading a file when it gets a 404 header? At least if that file isn't the main resource.

Comment: I saw similar behaviour with my app (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488917/node-js-express-js-on-windows-static-files-pending-for-up-to-two-minutes) - this looks like the same issue? Did you ever find a resolution? Never seen it happen with anything but Node.js...

Comment: I don't think it's the same issue. I've never seen the thing you describe, with existing files, happen.