# Node.js + Express.js on Windows: Static files pending for up to two minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static-files

I'm having an issue on my Windows environment with Node.Js/Express.js whereby static JS files can be marked as 'pending' in the browser (with caching disabled) for up to two minutes, after which they seem to download fine. This usually happens after a few refreshes.

There aren't any errors shown, so I'm not sure how to investigate further. The same code runs fine on a Mac OSX environment.

Node version is v0.10.31, Express is 4.8.5.

Code for static file is:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Chrome DevTools shows:

[image: Chrome DevTools Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using the same node and Express versions in your working OSX environment?

Comment: are you going through any kind of proxy?

Comment: It's the same version numbers on both environments, and no proxy set up.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was to set the resave property of express-session to false.

`app.use(session({ resave : false, ... }));`

My configuration: node v0.10.31, express v4.9.0, express-session v1.8.1

As session storage I use connect-mongo v0.4.1.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That solved the problem for me, using a similar configuration as yours with `connect-mongo`. Thank you. Wondering why that would cause this though.